# How The mimetype of google drive affects my real files?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

First of all, thanks for reading.

I was trying to figure out how the mimetype that google docs applies to the files can affect my "real" files in my computer.

I have two files with the same extension VBS (yes, visual basic script).
One was uploaded by me, and the other one was created with the code mirror google drive app.

I can open the second one with any google drive aplication for editting, I suppose it have the text mimetipe, but I can't open the other file (remember, the same vbs extension).

My question is, how can I change the mimetipe of all my VBS files, and how it will affect to the real files when synq with my computer?

Comment: The mimetype of a file is determined by its contents, not by the extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the content of both files is the same. The one that I uploaded was created by a single text editor, and it's content is plain text, the same as the other one. So we can determine both are plain text, may with different encoding, but text at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I told before, I don't understand why google is changing the mimetype of a file based on his extension, but here is a workaround which could be useful to people in my situation.

The easiest example is when you have script files in your drive folder, which are not other than plain textfiles (as visual basic script, or even bash files) but google drive assign a different mymetype based on its extension.

This function makes a copy, because I'm not 100% sure it is safe.
At the end of the function I have to add to a new folder (where the original file is) and remove the old one (root folder) because I don't know how to just move it. If anybody know how to improve it feel free to do it.

```
function changeMymeType(fileId){

  var file = DocsList.getFileById(fileId);
  var content = file.getContentAsString();
  var name="copy_"+file.getName();
  var folder = file.getParents();


  var newfile = DocsList.createFile(name, content, "text/plain");
  var oldFolder = newfile.getParents()[0];

  newfile.addToFolder(folder[0]);
  newfile.removeFromFolder(oldFolder);
};
```